# Magento 2 - show category tree in left navigation

Tags: magento2, php

Is there a way to get category tree list and limit the depth of it on the Magento 2 main category left sidebar subcategories list? Currently the list goes like this:

```
Categories:

- Subcategory 1
- Subcategory 2
- Subcategory 3
- Subcategory 4
...
```

The file which generates this list is within `Magento_Catalog/templates/navigation/left.phtml` with the following structure:

```
?>
<?php if (!$block->getCategory()) {
    return;
} ?>
<?php $_categories = $block->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories) ? count($_categories) : $_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if ($_count): ?>
    <div class="block filter">
        <div class="title">
            <strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shop By') ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Shopping Options') ?></strong>
            <dl class="options" id="narrow-by-list2">
                <dt><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Category') ?></dt>
                <dd>
                    <ol class="items">
                        <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                            <?php if ($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                                <li class="item">
                                    <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($block->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                                    <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_category->getProductCount() ?></span>
                                </li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </ol>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would like to show subcategory tree with depth 2 so it shows lvl2 subcategories also beneath it's parent category:

```
Categories:

- Subcategory 1
    Subcategory 1.1
    Subcategory 1.2
    Subcategory 1.3

- Subcategory 2
    Subcategory 2.1
    Subcategory 2.2
    Subcategory 2.3

- Subcategory 3
    Subcategory 3.1
    Subcategory 3.2
    Subcategory 3.3
...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We've created an extension that does exactly that: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar.

`$category` has a function `getChildrenNodes()` that returns all children. The function only works when flat categories are enabled. We use this function to retrieve subcategories for a category:

```
public function getSubcategories($category)
{
    if ($this->categoryFlatConfig->isFlatEnabled() && $category->getUseFlatResource())
        return (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();

    return $category->getChildren();
}
```

I was having with display of category and did some work around and edited code at 2 different files.
You have hard coded root category id as 1 but my root cat id was 2, So in block/sidebar.php, I changed it to store root category.
and 2nd I have changed.
copy following code from page-layout/2columns-left.xml and paste in layout/default.xml
  
        
            
        
    
Remove page-layout directory.

Comment: I have installed this extension but nothing is displaying in the sidebar.

Comment: yes same for me also, categories are not showing on sidebar

Comment: its working fine thanks a lot

Comment: @Silvan...what do you mean by "FLAT Categories" and you should update your extension for latest version so we can try

Comment: This version no longer works (2.4.3-pl) but there is a fork that does. See my answer below for the link. Cheers for the initial module bruv.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a reply to Silvan/Khurram Malik (above).

His linked Git module no longer works, but there is a fork that does work very well here: https://github.com/groomershop/magento2-category-sidebar

Same module, but with a dozen or so extra commits. Works great on my Mage 2.4.3-pl with a few style changes to suit us.

Thanks Silvan Khurram Malik for the initial module, and thanks to the Groomers for the working fork.